# Passing a value onto a prop - react

Tags: reactjs

I have a function component named ArticlePage with match as a prop

```
const ArticlePage = ({ match }) => {
    const name = match.params.name;
    const article = articleContent.find(article => article.name === name);

    if (!article) return <h1>Article does not exist!</h1>

    return (
        <>
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
        {article.content.map((paragraph, key) => (
            <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
        ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

Inside the App.js i called the function component without passing a data(, given these things i have 2 questions.

```
<Route path = "/article/:name" component = {ArticlePage} />
```

1. What is the purpose of destructuring in this line of code `const ArticlePage = ({ match }) => {` , based on my understanding the value that is somehow passed into the props was the /article/:name and i don't think this url parameter is either an array or an object.
2. What is the value getting passed onto the prop of ArticlePage? If it was the url parameter: /article/:name, how? Why does passing of data doesn't look like this `<Route path = "/article/:name" component = {ArticlePage(/article/:name)} />` like a normal function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [React Router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route) answers your questions. A `Route` component automatically passes a `match` prop to whatever component you supply. The `match` prop contains details about how the user's current URL matches the supplied path.

Since your supplied path includes `name` as a URL parameter, the value of `name` gets added to the `match` prop as `match.params.name`.